# Dynamically adding a new chart using chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, gitgraph.js

I am creating a data dashboard and I have stumbled on a problem that has me completely stumped. I am using chart.js as the chart renderer and jquery/js for the control of the dashboard. I want a user to be able to add a new chart via a button click, I can render the html content easily using the following:

```
   $('.graphs').append('<canvas id="' + name + '" data-dataset="2323"></canvas>');
```

This is creates the html as required, however chart.js requires a chunk of javascript per graph for the options and the dataset. I have no idea how to create this element of the application, I cant find any documentation that supports this method of dynamic graph creation. I am reasonably proficient at jquery, but this has me scratching my head.

I am looking for a method on how to create this code dynamically:

```
 new Chart(document.getElementById(name), {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: ["J", "F", "M", "A", "M", "J", "J", "A", "S", "O", "N", "D"],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: "Sales (millions)",
                        backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd"],
                        data: datasets1
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    legend: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    title: {
                        display: false,
                        text: 'Example Bar Chart'
                    },
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            gridLines: {
                                display: false
                            }
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{
                            gridLines: {
                                display: true
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                },

            });
```

Or some other approach.

Comment: You can do one thing. Just send an Ajax call on click of new chart button and then return html from that file and append that in a div. That will hopefully print the graph. Please try that and then let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the solution in this post is the only way I have found to achieve what I wanted. I cant take the credit as the answer here helped a lot: [Create multiple chart.js charts from jsonfile data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57645062/create-multiple-chart-js-charts-from-jsonfile-data)